# IntersectionObserver Error when embedding a YouTube video in an iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, embed

I am building a Chrome Extension. I'm having difficulty embedding a YouTube video using an iframe. Up until recently, everything worked fine, but, as of lately, I am not able to play the video anymore. I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to construct 'IntersectionObserver': Unable to get root node in main frame to track.
at new IZ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_GB-vflW62qlm/base.js:3707:122)
at new c2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_GB-vflW62qlm/base.js:3991:112)
at c2.create (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_GB-vflW62qlm/base.js:6988:333)
at Gi.<anonymous> (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:269)
at Gi.l.jb (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:308)
at Ki (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:505:143)
at Gi.l.oa (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:498:176)
at https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:557:378
```

Chrome bug maybe? Can anything be done to tackle the issue?
I checked the `window` object and `IntersectionObserver` exists, so I am quite curious as to why this might be happening.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this usually means that you need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: For an extension, it will be hard to put the code in the extension itself. I am also facing the same issue with the latest version of chrome  56.0.2924.87 on my extension while embedding youtube videos. This is possibly an issue with chrome browser itself.

Comment: @Terminal I am assuming the only thing that can be done is report the bug to Google. Unfortunately I doubt much can be done about this on our side, I've noticed a couple of more people on StackOverflow are facing the same issue.

Comment: I have opened an issue with the Chrome team, please star it here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=698545

Comment: @Jason Thank you, I've  starred the issue.